# cant get fields from belongstomany table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I cant get any fields from the subjects table below to display. I get the correct Students data, I get no errors but I dont get any any fields from Subjects table. Not sure what I am doing wrong . If I remove the where clause I get all the data from subjects so the issue is the where clause in the contain.

```
      $students = $this->Students->find()
                  ->contain([ 'Subjects' => function ($q) {
                      return $q
                           ->select(['id','name'])
                            ->where(['Subjects.id >' =>60])  ;  
                            }])   
                  ->select(['Students.id','Students.last_name','Students.first_name'])
                  ->where(['Students.student_inactive'=>false])
                    ->hydrate(true);


             foreach($students as $key=>$item2):
                    debug($item2);
             endforeach;


    /////////output
object(App\Model\Entity\Student) {

    'id' => (int) 24,
    'last_name' => 'Test',
    'first_name' => 'Cavr',
    'subjects' => [],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Students'

}
....
```

Comment: Everything looks good, are you sure you have record for subjects on given condition ? confirm that first.

Comment: yes i have plenty of subject ids over 60 so I have no idea what to do here

Comment: see the subjects in the output is an empty array?

Comment: this would not be the issue but just try selecting like select(['Subjects.id','Subjects.name']); there.

Comment: add the subject.id etc didnt work. I removed the where clause in the slect and this is the issue. Fot somereason it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sub = $this->Students->find()
            // ->contain(['Subjects'])
              ->select(['Students.id'])
               ->where(['Students.student_inactive'=>0 
                   ])
              ->order(['Students.first_name' => 'ASC'])
              ->hydrate(true);
```

I needed to use matching and also call the students_subjects table  subjects_students for some ODD reason

```
          $sub->matching('Subjects', function ($q) use ($subId) {

                 return $q
                   ->select(['Subjects.id','Subjects.name'])
                  ->where(['Subjects.id >' =>$subId]);
                });
```